# if -else condition in .xslt file in MULE

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

In my configuration.xml in MULE server 3.3.0 I pass MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS to .xslt file, below I copied my codes :

```
<logger 
  message="#[message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']]" 
  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

To pass IP address to XSLT, store it in a variable and pass that.

```
<set-variable 
  variableName="remoteClientAddress" 
  value = "#[message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']]"/>
```

Pass it to XSLT as:

```
<xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xsltFileName.xslt">
  <xm:context-property 
    key="remoteClientAddress" 
    value="#[remoteClientAddress]"/>
</xm:xslt-transformer>
```

In my XSLT, declared a param variable

```
<xsl:param  name="remoteClientAddress" />
```

and then use this variable as

```
<xsl:value-of select="$remoteClientAddress" />
```

Now I want to check **$remoteClientAddress** in .xslt file, that if it was equal to specific ip_address, then I could change in my XML(WSDL) file and if it wasn't equal nothing happen in my XML(WSDL) file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on previous posts you've made, my understanding is that you want to omit a particular part of the input XML if this match is true.  In that case, the following should be able to accomplish that (when added to your existing XSLT):

```
<xsl:template match="wsdl:operation[@name = 'GetISD']">
   <xsl:variable name="rcaTrimmed" 
          select="substring-before(substring-after($remoteClientAddress, '/'), ':')" />
   <xsl:if test="$rcaTrimmed != '123.12.12.123'">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This will *include* the operation only if the `$remoteClientAddress` is not equal to the specified address.

Comment: Thanks, my $remoteClientAddress format is like this : /127.0.0.1:53154 how can I omit extra part from it? and make it just like this : 127.0.0.1